# C# Read http post result

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpresponse, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have the following code in a MVC controller that is putting a sample guid string into a HttpResponseMessage:

```
public class CertifyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NewCertifyOfferRequestAsync(string requestString)
    {
        string activityId = "30dd879c-ee2f-11db-8314-0800200c9a66";

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StringContent(activityId);
        return httpResponseMessage;
    }

}
```

I am calling this Controller through a console app using the following code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:84928/");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string requestString = "df5f5587-f1ef-449a-9d20-7f386ea638a8";

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Certify/NewCertifyOfferRequestAsync", requestString);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string activityId = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Received activity id: " + activityId);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to receive activityId "30dd879c-ee2f-11db-8314-0800200c9a66" in the response. But instead activityId is getting "StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n}" from the ReadAsStringAsync call.

How should I change the assignment of activityId so that it gets the activityId being generated in the Controller?

Comment: Are you sure that the activityId does not get your result along with all other things? Post the entire result here.

Comment: Is this your _actual_ WebAPI code? It looks like you're returning an `HttpResponseMessge` that gets serialized to string in its entirety.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico I posted the entire activityId response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() is returning.

Comment: @CodeCaster I posted my entire Controller code.

Comment: Unless you're using MVC 6, that's an MVC controller. WebAPI controllers inherit from ApiController.

Comment: I narrowed the scope of this question to a normal MVC controller and will post a new question for calling a WebApi Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is webapi, you should be able to change your method signature to return a "string" instead of HttpResponseMessage.

e.g

```
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

for detail sample, you can use visual studio to create a WebApi web app, and look at the "ValuesController.cs"

Comment: Instead of creating a HttpResponseMessage, I changed the return type of the post function to Task<string> and returned the guid directly (return actvityId). I could get the activityId in the calling console app. Could you also tell how I should change my receiving code to get the activityId if I am keeping the HttpResponseMessage creation as it is?

Comment: I haven`t tried, but i think if you strongly type it and return with content type set to "application/json". then on your client side, deserialize the content into an object. you should get what you want.